# Why is view field output different for anonymous users?

Tags: views

I got this html when user is Logged in :

```
  <div class="views-row views-row-2 views-row-even">
    <div class="views-field views-field-name">
      <span class="field-content">
        <a href="/30zin/taxonomy/term/8">cook</a>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

and got this when user is logged out :

```
<div class="views-row views-row-2 views-row-even">
   <a href="node/6"> </a>
   <div class="views-field views-field-name">
     <a href="node/6">
     <span class="field-content"></span>
     </a>
    <a href="/30zin/taxonomy/term/8">cook</a>
  </div>
```

Additional notes (from comments):

- Taxonomy view
- Tried clearing caches
- No server side caching set up

Comment: any ideas about what? what is the question? is this not expected behaviour?

Comment: about why html is differnt when user is logged out ? @Geoff

Comment: numerous things change when a user logs out, is it affecting your site, or this is a curiosity thing? If it is affecting your site, how does the change in html, change the functionality of the site, do you have any access controls or modules in effect (node access, field access, etc)

Comment: thanks for your answer , yes it's affecting , i am designing a new website and i created a view from taxonomy and i give them style like this : a:font-size:0 , background-image:url;
as you can see i got 3 a tag when user is logged out , that's mess it up . and yes i have access

Comment: do you have cached pages set for anonymous users or any other cache setups (server side caching), and does clearing the cache make any difference?

Comment: really strange , no there is no cache

Comment: (1) Are you overriding the fields on the Views UI? (2) Are there any modules related with permissions (eg NodeAccess etc), (3) Are you using Fields or View Modes to display these results? Also I would suggest to **export** this Views and copy paste it here.